# Prevent WebView from opening browser ANDROID [react-native]

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm working on a react-native app using WebView.
Here's the code of web view:

```
    <WebView
      ref={webView}
      onLoad={onLoad}
      onMessage={() => {}}
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      source={{ uri: PLATFORM_URL }}
      onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
    />
```

I'd like to prevent the web-view from opening browser when some buttons are clicked.
In particular, I'm struggling on a  with target blank, and in iOS it actually redirect inside the webview, but on Android it opens the browser.

I've found one possible solution, that consist on injecting javascript code that is able to remove all target-blank s.

Is this the only solution? or is there a way to intercept that the webview is going to open the web browser?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps although it is late. Try using props **onShouldStartLoadWithRequest** like this

```
<WebView
 source={{uri:'https://stackoverflow.com/'}}
 onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={request => {
  if (request.url.includes('https')) {
      return false;
  } else return true;
 }}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems too late, but I will give simple solution I found.

```
setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
```

This prop prevents from opening the browser in Android.